# Two column layout for a list of content

Tags: html, css

I want to print a list of blog news, each one has a static size image, a title and a short summary.

The listing must be a two column, I don't want to create 2 divs to solve this problem, unless there's no other way.

Here's an example of how it's been now. But the box sizes must be the same, otherwise the smaller box will have a large padding to fit the size of the other box.

http://jsfiddle.net/GTh4Y/

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner" style="height: 320px; background-color: #fa81ee"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="height: 200px; background-color: #ef99ae"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="height: 280px; background-color: #eafe41"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="height: 300px; background-color: #ef5ea8"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="height: 150px; background-color: #98f718"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="height: 160px; background-color: #f21ae9"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="height: 320px; background-color: #8a62e7"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="height: 110px; background-color: #ab43a8"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
    width: 810px;
    height: auto;
}
.inner {
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

How can I do that without adding 2 divs?

I want the result to be like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/q8ew8/

Comment: You have image, title, summary. Which goes where? All in the same div? Top to bottom?

Comment: yes, all in the same div (for the example I posted, they should be all in div.inner).

Comment: why do you have different `height` for divs then?

Comment: because the summary and the title length may differ

Comment: If only there was a simple intended way to do this with CSS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts

Comment: Anthony, your comment solved my problem, you should create an answer with it. I'll definitely mark as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, is there any reason you don't want to add two internal div's as column containers (this is a far simpler solution)?

So in order to do what your asking and not have it look completely terrible, you'd have to rearrange the div.inner's that you have there then float them to the left.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="inner" style="height: 320px; background-color: #fa81ee">1</div>
<div class="inner" style="height: 200px; background-color: #ef99ae">2</div>
<div class="inner" style="height: 150px; background-color: #98f718">5</div>
<div class="inner" style="height: 280px; background-color: #eafe41">3</div>
<div class="inner" style="height: 300px; background-color: #ef5ea8">4</div>
<div class="inner" style="height: 320px; background-color: #8a62e7">7</div>
<div class="inner" style="height: 160px; background-color: #f21ae9">6</div>
<div class="inner" style="height: 110px; background-color: #ab43a8">8</div>
</div>
```

I added a number to them to show their original position.  So basically what I did was re-positioned them so that the left column item has about the same height as a number of right column items (1 is about the same as 2 + 5, 3 and 4 are close, and 7 is larger than 6 and 8).  As for the CSS, you just add float:left; to .inner.

```
.container {
    width: 810px;
    height: auto;
}
.inner {
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid white;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

But really the best way to do this so that all of the items in each column were touching without excessive white space would be to simply add a second set of div's.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got the exact idea of what you are asking you can use `column-count` to get the display you are looking for if you are ok with changing your HTML:

```
ul {
    /*styles*/
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
}
```

### [Demo Fiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/yjcLh/1/)

---

More styled fiddle :

### [Demo Fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/Tk3LQ/) / Watch [Fullscreen](http://jsfiddle.net/Tk3LQ/show/)

Comment: There's only one problem, I want the div with content "2" to be the second in the code.

Comment: I was mentioning the other way, but in the code it's not the same sequency. its 1 3 2 4. Not 1 2 3 4.